# Xstream: How to deserialize Xml with array

Tags: java, xstream

I've an xml with a repeating array element, how do I deserialize it?

```
<root>
 <values>
   <val1>afa</val1>
   <val2>asgfasg</val2>
 </values>
 <values>
   <val1>hkjvlk</val1>
   <val2>sdsdgsdg</val2>
 </values>
 ...
</root>

 XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
 xstream.alias("values", Inventory.class);
 InventoryResult inventory = (InventoryResult) xstream.fromXML(data.toString());
```

&

```
public class InventoryResult {
    private Inventory values;
}
```

I've tried List, Inventory[], but none of them work.

Comment: How can two variables have same name as array? Don't get it :( Where did you get the xml from, what is the source? XSD?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, the tag names are different. Updated the xml above. Source of xml is some legacy app that doesn't even have an xsd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all is this only a part of entire xml doc?
if yes

```
<root>
    <values>
      <val1>afa</val1>
    </values>
    <values>
      <val2>hkjvlk</val2>
    </values>
  </root>
```

This is the serialized form of

```
values [] root = {new values("afa", null), new values(null, "hkjvlk")};
```

where Class values will look like this

```
class values{
    String val1;
    String val2;
    public values (String str, String str1){
        val1 = str;
        val2 = str1;                
    }
}
```

Comment: The xml tag <values> repeats. Not sure how your solution helps in that case.

Comment: Each values is a root array element, Isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

I would advice to write your own Converter: http://x-stream.github.io/converter-tutorial.html